# passing command line argument present in a file

Tags: shell, automation, command-line-arguments

I have an executable which expects certain command line parameters. I am automating the installation of a software. This executable is part of the automation shell script. One of the parameters to this script is stored in a file let say, file.txt. It has a string which is an argument to this executable. How do I pass this string to the executable in shell script?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `read param < file.txt` then `prog-name $param`.  However, it is probable that the parameter is not stored as the first non-space string in the file, and it might have embedded spaces.  If not, then you need to supply more detail.

Comment: Hey, thankfully for me the file only has one string without any spaces and this works. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This works in `bash`:

```
echo -l > foo
ls $(< foo)
```